# asp.net core mvc Javascript break point not hitting in debug mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The break ppint is on $('FromDate').datetimepicker

[image]

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#FromDate').datetimepicker({ 
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY', 
        minDate: moment().millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0),
        clear : false 
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, if the answer solved your question, please mark it for helping more people. If not, we may be able to continue to explore solutions. Thank you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 3):

[Visual Studio .NET debugger doesn't stop on breakpoints when you debug ASP.NET pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/visualstudio/general/debugger-not-stop-breakpoint)

For JavaScript debug, I suggest you could try using browser debug tool(F12).It is more flexible.

**For example**

> Debugging js in Google Chrome

1.Press `F12` to open Dev tools control panel.
2.Open `Source` Tab and select the file where you code is from directory. 
3.Add `Breakpoint` to the line you need to debug. 
4.Press `F5` to refresh your page.
[image]